# OpenGL C++ Plain Subdivison in QUADS (Radiosity) patches on arrays

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to implement Radiosity in OpenGL for my project. Firstly, I need to be able to draw a plane (representing walls). And then be able to subdivide that plane into patches or smaller quads within that plane by using a method.

The difficulty is to draw them in a way when I draw another plain (another wall) if the height and width aren't the same the vertices are not aligned creating T vertices which I want to avoid.

I was thinking in something like

```
void drawPlaneMethod(float width, float height, int numberOfSubDivisions) {}
```

However I might need to use ratios or something related. I don't care about the Z-axis coordinate as I can rotate my planes after they are constructed. The number of sub-division on height and width must be proportional to the other wall.

If this is not possible, then I can do that by using planes of the same height and width, however it looks unrealistic as I end up a heigh ceiling. And I can't make windows, doors without having to carefully creating many planes to represent a single wall.

Then I gotta face another problem that is to be able to store information on each patch such as colour, radiosity values etc. I was thinking of using arrays of objects (Patches) and representing the planes indexes to access the patches objects. As I am not very good with c++ I am finding it hard to use arrays of any sort (2 dimensional arrays would be ideal I guess).

Any insight on this problem?

PS: I am using glBegin(GL_QUADS), I can change later on for VBOs once I do the basics of my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you will want to create more complex geometry (windows, doors, stairs) in a 3D modeling application, export it from there and import it into your application.

If you build your geometry that way, you can also enforce that all edges of all planes/quads are connected - and when you divide them all evenly into the same number of faces, the new vertices will naturally meet at the edges:

[image]

Assuming you have a 3D vector class with some basic arithmetic operators...

```
using Position3 = std::array<float, 3>; //math operators left as excercise :)
```

you could represent a plane/quad simply as an array of its 4 vertices' positions...

```
using Plane = std::array<Position3, 4>;
```

Let's assume the vertices are in counter clockwise order.
If we want to subdivide a quad into four quads, we will need 5 new vertices, let's call them p1 through 5:

[image: excuse my paint skills]

These aren't hard to calculate:

```
Position3 e1 = plane[1] - plane[0];
Position3 e2 = plane[2] - plane[3];
Position3 e3 = plane[3] - plane[0];
Position3 e4 = plane[2] - plane[1];

Position3 p1 = e1 * 0.5f + plane[0];
Position3 p2 = e2 * 0.5f + plane[3];
Position3 p3 = e3 * 0.5f + plane[0];
Position3 p4 = e4 * 0.5f + plane[1];

Position3 e5 = p2 - p1;
Position3 p5 = e5 * 0.5f + p1;
```

and from these and our original vertices we can build the 4 new quads:

```
{{ plane[0], p1, p5, p3 },
 { p1, plane[1], p4, p5 },
 { p5, p4, plane[2], p2 },
 { p3, p5, p2, plane[3] }}
```

Now with a simple recursive function we can divide any planar quad into 4, 16, 64, ... smaller quads.

If you also want to be able to divide it into NxN smaller quads, you'll want to calculate N-1 points along each edge, e.g. for 3x3 at `e1 * 1/3`, `e1 * 2/3` and so on. An iterative approach would probably be easier there, and you could even implement it in a geometry shader if you wanted.

Here's the result of running my little example algorithm ([full source here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b01db8e00f50c872)) on a quad:
[image]

If you are trying to implement radiosity on the GPU though, you might not even have to implement any of this yourself, if you use [hardware tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics)).

Comment: That's really nice. I kinda knew that, but I don't know how to represent each square. Do you have any link or paper that can help me with the representation of a plane and how to subdivide?

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta I expanded a bit on that

Comment: I can't use tesselation. It might be a function I might implement after I finish with the basics. Thanks for your help, I think this will get me going. Many thanks!