# OpenGL C++ Plane Subdivison in QUADS, Iterative approach

Tags: c++, opengl

I have done a recursive method for subdivision accordingly to this post:
[OpenGL C++ Plain Subdivison in QUADS (Radiosity) patches on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780788/opengl-c-plain-subdivison-in-quads-radiosity-patches-on-arrays). However, I need it to be iterative because the indices on its array is messed up and it impossible for me to interpolate colors manually.

The indexes the array are as follows:

```
//  ___________________ 
// |    |    |    |    |
// | 15 | 14 | 11 | 10 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// | 12 | 13 |  8 |  9 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// |  3 |  2 |  7 |  6 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// |  0 |  1 |  4 |  5 |
// |____|____|____|____|
```

and I want them to be like this:

```
//  ___________________ 
// |    |    |    |    |
// | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
// |____|____|____|____|
// |    |    |    |    |
// |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
// |____|____|____|____|
```

On that post, the user melak47 even suggested how to do that method in a iterative way, however, I didn't make it very well.

Can anyone have a look at this and give me a code or a good suggestion on how to solve this problem, thank you!

How can I get the vertices with float values? Each vertex have x y and z coordinates, I can't multiply a vertex by 0 or I lose its coordinates. I got a bit lost there!

any1 understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get four Vertices from the patch
Vect zero = patch.getVertex(0);
Vect one = patch.getVertex(1);
Vect two = patch.getVertex(2);
Vect three = patch.getVertex(3);

Vect e1 = one.subVect(zero);
Vect e2 = two.subVect(three);
Vect e3 = three.subVect(zero);
Vect e4 = two.subVect(one);

vector<Vect> eOne, eTwo, eThree, eFour;

GLint patchesRowColumn = static_cast<GLint>(pow(2, iterations));
for (GLint i = 0; i <= patchesRowColumn; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        eOne.push_back(zero);
        eTwo.push_back(three);
        eThree.push_back(zero);
        eFour.push_back(one);
    } else if (i == patchesRowColumn) {
        eOne.push_back(one);
        eTwo.push_back(two);
        eThree.push_back(three);
        eFour.push_back(two);
    } else {
        GLfloat fraction = ((GLfloat) i) / patchesRowColumn;
        eOne.push_back(e1.multVect(fraction).addVect(zero));
        eTwo.push_back(e2.multVect(fraction).addVect(three));
        eThree.push_back(e3.multVect(fraction).addVect(zero));
        eFour.push_back(e4.multVect(fraction).addVect(one));
    }
}

GLfloat fraction = 1.0f / patchesRowColumn;

vector<Patch> p;
for (GLint x = 0; x < patchesRowColumn; x++) { // row
    for (GLint y = 0; y < patchesRowColumn; y++) { // column
        std::cout << "\r";
        std::cout << ++iterationCounter;

        Vect vect0, vect1, vect2, vect3;

        // Vect0
        if (x == 0) {
            if (y == 0) {
                vect0 = zero;
            } else {
                vect0 = eOne[y];
            }
        } else {
            if (y == 0) {
                vect0 = eThree[x];
            } else {
                GLfloat zeroFraction = ((GLfloat) y) * fraction;
                vect0 = eFour[x].subVect(eThree[x]).multVect(zeroFraction).addVect(eThree[x]);
            }
        }

        // Vect1
        if (x == 0) {
            vect1 = eOne[y + 1];
        } else {
            GLfloat oneFraction = ((GLfloat) (y + 1)) * fraction;
            vect1 = eFour[x].subVect(eThree[x]).multVect(oneFraction).addVect(eThree[x]);
        }

        // Vect2
        GLfloat twoFraction = ((GLfloat) (y + 1)) * fraction;
        vect2 = eFour[x + 1].subVect(eThree[x + 1]).multVect(twoFraction).addVect(eThree[x + 1]);

        // Vect3
        if (y == 0) {
            vect3 = eThree[x + 1];
        } else {
            GLfloat threeFraction = ((GLfloat) y) * fraction;
            vect3 = eFour[x + 1].subVect(eThree[x + 1]).multVect(threeFraction).addVect(eThree[x + 1]);
        }

        p.push_back(Patch(vect0, vect1, vect2, vect3));
    }
}
```

I finally managed to do it on the way above. A bit hard to explain, but hopefully it will be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative approach requires you to execute two nested for loops rather than using recursion.

```
vector<Patch> Scene::subdivide(Patch& patch, GLint subdivisions = 2) {
   vector<Patch> result;
   // Get four Vertices from the patch
   Vect ll = patch.getVertex(0);
   Vect lr = patch.getVertex(1);
   Vect ur = patch.getVertex(2);
   Vect ul = patch.getVertex(3);
   float height = ???; // find the vertical distance between ll and ul
   float width = ???; // find the horizontal distance between ll and lr
   float rowHeight = height / subdivisions;
   float colWidth = width / subdivisions;
   for (int row = 0; row < subdivisions; ++row) {
      float rowBottom = row * rowHeight;
      float rowTop = rowBottom + rowHeight;
      for (int col = 0; col < subdivisions; ++col) {
         float colLeft = col * colWidth;
         float colRight = colLeft + colWidth;
         // Create 4 vertices created by combining colLeft, colRight,
         // rowBottom and rowTop with the Vect ll
         ...
         // Create a patch from the 4 vertices
         Patch p = ???;
         // add it to the result
         result.push_back(p);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

You might still be able to use recursion, but it would require you to do a lot of math in this section:

```
} else {
    vector<Patch> result2;
    for (auto& x : result) { // Take each patch and subdive them further
        auto subplanes = subdivide(x, iterations - 1);
        // Storing patches subdivisions to be returned
        result2.insert(result2.end(), subplanes.begin(), subplanes.end());
    }
    return result2; // Completed, return result
}
```

Because you would need take the result apart and divide it into rows by finding the appropriate insertion point, and then taking a subset of the returned subplanes and inserting them there.  I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: I am lost here:

    // Create 4 vertices created by combining colLeft, colRight,
    // rowBottom and rowTop with the Vect ll
    Vect v0, v1, v2, v3;
   
    // Create a patch from the 4 vertices
    Patch p = Patch(v0, v1, v2, v3);
    // add it to the result
    result.push_back(p);